# how to obtain the drop down selected option from a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to extract selected option from a dynamically created table column. The code below works to extract the input values but not for the drop down values.

Dynamically generate HTML

```
          $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='Letter"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Letter' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='Start"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Start'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='End"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='End'  class='form-control input-md'></td> <td>  <select name='cars' id='cars'><option value='All'>All</option><option value='Even'>Even</option><option value='Odd'>Odd</option></select></td>");
```

javascript code

```
    // start from the second row as the first one only contains the table's headers
    for (let i = 1; i < targetTableRows.length; i++) {
          var Inventorydict ={}

        // loop over the contents of each row
        for (let j = 0; j < targetTableRows[i].cells.length; j++) {
            // something we could use to identify a given item
            let currColumn = tableHeaders.cells[j].innerHTML;
            // the current <td> element
            let currData = targetTableRows[i].cells[j];
            // the input field in the row
            let currDataInput = currData.querySelector('input');
 
            // is the current <td> element containing an input field? print its value.
            // Otherwise, print whatever is insside
            currDataInput ? console.log(`${currColumn}: ${currDataInput.value}`) 
              : console.log(`${currColumn}: ${currData.document.getElementById("addressType")}`); 
            if (currDataInput) {

                Inventorydict[currColumn.replace(/\s/g, '')] = currDataInput.value;
  
            } else {
                Inventorydict[currColumn.replace(/\s/g, '')] = currData.innerHTML;
            }
             
        }
```

I use this to get the input values

```
    let currDataInput = currData.querySelector('input');
```

I tried using this to get the selected option

```
            let addresstype = currColumn.getElementById("addressType")
```

but it does not work. How can I obtain the drop down selected option ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currColumn is being given a value in this point of your code:

```
let currColumn = tableHeaders.cells[j].innerHTML;
```

The `innerHTML` property returns a string, that's why you cannot use querySelector on it.

First of all, if you want to get the value of the `select` once every row, you should move that section outside of that inner cycle, that loops through each cell of that row.

Then, you will need to get a reference of the `tr` html element. This should be `targetTableRows[i]`.

You can get your `select` element by using the querySelector on this element:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < targetTableRows.length; i++) {
    var Inventorydict ={}
    
    // ...
    
    let select = targetTableRows[i].querySelector("select");
    let selectValue = select.value; // This will map to the "value" property of the selected option
}
```

However, please keep in mind that you should really select elements based on their class or input name, not by their type. Also, you should not assign the same id to multiple element of your page. This will help you avoid errors that will be hard to troubleshoot.